# Giving constraints in Optimization using Pulp

Tags: python-2.7, pulp

I am currently working on an Optimization problem using Pulp module in Python. I want to set my variables to be integral multiple of 7500.So I created a constriant as given below but it is showing error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pulp import *

prob = LpProblem('Cost minimization' , LpMinimize)
X = LpVariable.dicts('',tsap.varName, lowBound=0, upBound=None,     cat=LpInteger)
prob += lpSum( X[i] * j for i,j in zip(tsap.varName, tsap.coeff)),'Total cost'

l=7500

for i in X:
prob += i % l == 0

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-73548ad8b39f> in <module>()
        1 for i in X:
  ----> 2     prob += i % l == 0
        3 

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Is there any way to achieve the desired goal?

Comment: You're trying to use the modulo operator, which you can't do in linear programming. But, you could maybe set up a dummy LpVariable, k, which has to be an integer, and then add a constraint that i == 7500*k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the modulo operator in pulp as that would become a non-linear problem.

However, the simple solution is to keep `X[i]` integer and then in you constraints use `7500*X[i]` and report the solution accordingly.